# jQuery Concatenation or selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have the following:

```
changeDegreeLabel: {
        "Certificate" : "Diploma"
}

this.changeDegreeLabel = function(labelReplacements)
{
```

this one works

```
        $.each(labelReplacements, function(oldValue, newValue) {
            $('#programList dt:contains(' + oldValue + ')')
                .text(newValue);
        });
```

this one doesn't work yet

```
        $.each(labelReplacements, function(oldValue, newValue) {
            $("#program_id>optgroup[label="+oldValue+"]")
                .attr('label', newValue);
        });
 }
```

Basically, I just want to change Certificate to Diploma.  It works in the first function, but not the second.  I've tried multiple different quote combinations for concatenating the variable in the attribute selector, but to no avail.  Thoughts?

EDIT:  Here's the HTML for the 'this one doesn't work yet' portion

```
<select id="program_id" class="required" name="program_id">
<option value="" selected="selected">— Select —</option>
<optgroup label="Associate">
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Certificate">
</optgroup>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? It's kinda tough for us to tell you if your selector is right without that.

Comment: Not sure there's anything wrong with your loop code: http://jsfiddle.net/PA5xF/

Comment: Hmm must be something odd happening within the class/method handling.  I'll take a deeper look..

Comment: My form was refreshing based on some other triggers, so not a jQuery issue.  Didn't know about jsFiddle, so at least I got that out of it.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Yep, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/) are both good for HTML/JS/CSS, [codepad](http://codepad.org/) or [codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) are good for PHP, and [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is good for SQL. I'm sure there are more, but those are the ones I use most frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the quotes around the value, your string might contain spaces for example. You need to use single quotes or escape doubles quotes:

```
$('#program_id>optgroup[label="'+ oldValue +'"]')
 -^-                          -^-          -^--^-

//OR

$("#program_id>optgroup[label=\""+ oldValue +"\"]")
                             -^-             -^-
```

Comment: "it is necessary in latest jQuery versions" Are you sure? I've tested on jq2.0 and works without quotes

Comment: No, I wasn't sure, but I was too lazy to test, thanks for info.

Comment: @Travesty3: Agree. I _always_ add the quotes. I've encountered this problem so many times that it's mostly reflex now...